# Using SQLite when a parameter of the data is only known at runtime

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am writing an Android app that continuously reads data from multiple bluetooth low energy peripherals and stores the data in a database. However, the number of these sensors varies and is only known at runtime. How should I format my database to accommodate this? Is it possible to create a table with a number of columns known at runtime, or should I represent each array of sensor data as a row in the table and just update the row as more data comes in? Perhaps another strategy?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a table with a number of columns known at runtime

Yes, though that may be awkward to work with.

> should I represent each array of sensor data as a row in the table and just update the row as more data comes in?

That seems to be the same as your first idea, so I am guessing that I am just not understanding it.

> Perhaps another strategy?

Have a `readings` table with an identifier of the BLE device and the reading. Insert new rows for each device/reading pair.

If you need to treat a set of readings as a unit:

- Have a `readings_set` table, with whatever data you need for all of the readings (e.g., timestamp)
- Have `readings` have a foreign key relationship back to `readings_set`, so you can find all of the individual readings for a particular set

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear, I don't have a complete understanding of Sql tables.

Comment: For what you suggested, i'm unsure of which strategy to use. Say after a day I wanted to retrieve the data, but it has to be in order for each device, i.e. in the order it was received by the app. Would that be too difficult with using only one table which I'm assuming would have a lot of rows?

Comment: @eagren: Your problem is not "one table" versus having many tables. Having one table in general is much easier. Your problem may be the "lot of rows", and that is less of a problem for SQLite as it is for Android, as you only have so much memory to work with.

Comment: Ok. To clarify what I meant earlier by representing each device as a row and then updating the row was instead of adding a new row for each device/reading pair, you instead udpate the existing row and add in the new reading to the corresponding device

Comment: @eagren: If all you need are the latest readings, using SQLite is overkill. Just store them in a simple file (e.g., JSON) or use `SharedPreferences` or something. I assumed that you needed the full history of readings, in which case SQLite makes more sense.

Comment: You're correct that I need the full history of readings. It's also important that when I export them to excel or something like that the data is in order

Comment: @eagren: "You're correct that I need the full history of readings" -- then updating a row will not help you. That *replaces* the existing data. You need to *insert* rows. "It's also important that when I export them to excel or something like that the data is in order" -- use `ORDER BY` in your SQLite query to return them in a specific order.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing: you mentioned using an additional table if I need to treat readings as a unit. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @eagren: Suppose that you have N sensors. Further suppose that you are getting readings from all N sensors at a time. This will result in N rows in your `readings` table, one per sensor. If you need to be able to ask the database "give me all of the readings for this specific time", it may be simpler for you keep track of those sets of readings in their own table. So for a set of N sensors, you have N rows in the `readings` table and 1 row in the `reading_sets` table, where the `readings` table have a foreign key back to the associated `reading_sets` row representing that set.

Comment: I see. Thanks again